# I want to store two integer value with an integer key value

Tags: java, android

I want to store two integer values using an integer key, also please tell how to store and retrieve data using the key.

i already tried this :

```
static HashMap<Integer, User> nodes = new HashMap<Integer, User>();               


public User( int b, int c) {

    xco = b;
    yco = c;
}
```

and i stored values into it as

```
 User.nodes.put(User.key,new User((int)upx,(int)upy));
```

but I can't retrieve the data using the key

Comment: Yes, you can achieve it by start writing some code. Convert your words to code. nothing hard.

Comment: Use `java.util.Map`. It stores key,value pair. Some implementations are HashMap, LinkedHashMap, TreeMap etc.. So you can simple create a hashmap line `Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>`

Comment: Two integers in a single key? OK, you can sum (say) 2014 and 7 in such a way they are recognizable: 102014200007 (and it's still a single number). You then have to implement your own code to sum the values to the 1000020000 **mask** and retrieve them from it (possibly passing from string conversion?).

Comment: hey see my answer you may get help from it use SparseIntArray

Comment: Is this your `User` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your question isn't much describe your requirement and what have you tried so far.

But assuming your question you can try as follows.

you can create a `Map<Key,Value>` Integer value as a `Key` and Integer `List<Integer>` as `Value`

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map=new HashMap<>();
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);

map.put(1,list);// key is 1, values 1 and 2
```

you can retrieve values as follows

```
map.get(1) // will return list which contains values 1 and 2
```

Edit:

```
HashMap<Integer, User> nodes = new HashMap<Integer, User>();               
User user=new User(1,2);// creating a user

nodes.put(1,user);
```

Now you can get values

```
nodes.get(1)// will return user
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answers

I stored it using hash map and list

static HashMap> nodes = new HashMap>();

Answer (score 0):

use The `Map Interface`

A map has the form `Map <K, V>` where:

1. K: specifies the type of keys maintained in this map.*
2. V: defines the type of mapped values.

you need to have an object for your 2 integer values:

```
class Object{
   Integer int1;     
   Integer int2; 
}

Map<Integer,Object> map;
```

To get value

```
Object result =  map.get(1) // will return the first object which contain 2 integers
```

You can get your 2 integers using `Object.int1` and `Object.int2`

Comment: It's good that you did not spoon fed him the actual code :-)

Comment: yes i am using this method, please tellme how to retrive the two integer data using get method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question.
If your values ​​are observably large, you can use the method: v1 * 10^n + v2
where v2 < 10^n

Answer (score 0):

use [SparseIntArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html)  it is efficient way to store `int` key value pair

```
 SparseIntArray  sparseIntArray new SparseIntArray();
 sparseIntArray.put(int_key,int_value);
```

while for geting value

```
sparseIntArray.get(int_key);
```